Prove that on a Hausdorff $\sigma$-compact space every Baire measure is tight
Let $X$ be a topological space. We say that an open set $U\subseteq X$ is functionally open if there are a continuous function $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ and an open set $V\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ such that $U=f^{-1}(V)$.
Denote by $\mathbf{Ba}(X)$ the $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ generated by all functionally open subsets of $X$.
Suppose that $X$ is a Hausdorff $\sigma$-compact space. Prove that every measure $\mu:\mathbf{Ba}(X)\to \mathbb{R}$ is tight, that is, for all $\varepsilon >0$ there's a compact $K\subseteq X$ such that $\lambda (A)<\varepsilon $ for all $A\in \mathbf{Ba}(X)$ with $A\cap K=\emptyset $.

What I did:
According to the 7.1.8. Corollary of the book "Measure Theory" by V.I. Bogachev, every measure $\mu:\mathbf{Ba}(X)\to \mathbb{R}$ is outer regular, that is, for any $A\in\mathbf{Ba}(X)$ and $\varepsilon >0$ there's a closed set $F\subseteq A$ such that $\mu (A\setminus F)<\varepsilon $.
Since $\mu$ is outer regular, I chose a closed set $F\subseteq X$ such that $\mu (X\setminus F)<\varepsilon /2$.
I chose a collection $\{K_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of compact sets satisfying $X=\cup _{n\in\mathbb{N}}\!\,K_n$ and $K_n\subseteq K_{n+1}$ and a natural $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\mu (F)-\mu ^*(F\cap K_n)<\varepsilon /2$ with $\mu^*$ denoting the outer measure of $\mu$.
But I couldn't prove that $\mu^*(X\setminus (F\cap K_n))<\varepsilon $, which would finish the proof.
